# Bootstrap 4 white space on right side

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4, removing-whitespace

Can anybody explain me, why I am getting a white space on the right side with Bootstrap 4?

This is the main code block of the page

```
<main id="intro" role="intro" class="inner text-center">
    <h2>Lorum Ipsum</h2>
    <p class="lead">Register now!</p>
    <p class="lead">
      <a href="<?php echo HOME ?>/register" class="btn btn-light btn-lg">Click here</a>
    </p>
</main>
```

And the custom CSS

```
html,
body,
header,
#intro {
  height: 100%;
}

#intro {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, .7), rgba(0, 0, 0, .7)), url("../img/intro-1.jpg") no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 250px;
}
```

If needed I can provide an url to the website.
thanks for any help!!

**EDIT:**
Here is the website link:
http://drohnen-vz.de

Comment: The code to repro the issue seems to be incomplete. Please post all of the relevant code.

Comment: Especially since you do not seem to be using expected BS classes.

Comment: I get no white space using your code:https://www.bootply.com/DFqmgGyNzY

Comment: Please check my website link I provided maybe it helps

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Further to Paulie's comment, the process of creating a [MCVE] helps you to eliminate what is not causing issues, in this case, if you had bothered, you would see that main had nothing to do with the error so the code in your question is of no use whatsoever

Comment: i cant see any white blocks in the reference sit you have provided

Comment: it is already fixed bro

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your issue is because your footer has a row without a container so you get margin out of the right side.  A little tip for you in future, inspect your elements and delete them until the error disappears, then you know what is causing the error

Fix your page by adding a container class to your footer:

```html
<footer class="pt-4 my-md-5 pt-md-5 border-top text-center container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md">
      <img class="mb-2" src="img/logo-kurz.svg" alt="" width="75" height="75">
      <small class="d-block mb-3 text-muted">© 2018</small>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-md text-center">
      <h5>Links</h5>
      <ul class="list-unstyled text-small">
        <li><a class="text-muted" href="http://drohnen-vz.de/agb">AGB</a></li>
        <li><a class="text-muted" href="http://drohnen-vz.de/impressum">Impressum</a></li>
        <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Datenschutzrichtlinien</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-md text-center">
      <h5>Partner</h5>
      <ul class="list-unstyled text-small">
        <li><img src="img/partner-1.svg" width="100px"> <img src="img/partner-dhl.svg" width="100px"></li>
        <li><br></li>
        <li><img src="img/partner-sofort.svg" width="100px"> <img src="img/partner-paypal.svg" width="100px"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Thank you soo much. I always focused on the header part, bc I believed this was responsible for that. Saved my day!

Comment: Yesh. This is usually the reason.